What is the difference between abstract classes and interfaces in Java?
I'm trying to understand the key differences between abstract classes and interfaces in Java, especially in the context of object-oriented design. Here's what I know so far:
Abstract Classes:

Can have both abstract and concrete methods.
Can have member variables.
Can be extended by only one subclass (Java doesn't support multiple inheritance).
A subclass can inherit the implementation of abstract methods from the abstract class.

Interfaces:

Cannot have concrete methods (until Java 8, when default methods were introduced).
Cannot have member variables, only constants (though Java 8 also introduced static methods).
Can be implemented by multiple classes (supports multiple inheritance of behavior).
A class can implement multiple interfaces.

However, I'm unclear about the following:

When should I use one over the other?
What are the specific performance or design implications when choosing between an abstract class and an interface?
Can an abstract class implement an interface, or is that unnecessary?
What are the major use cases for each?
Could anyone please clarify the differences and when to use each in real-world scenarios?


Please check out some of these prior similar questions on this site. This is my preferred search strategy when looking for answers on this site, and you might find it helpful too. Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please check out the [tour] and [help] links for information on how to best use the site and get the most out of the site.

By the way, there's a glaring error: "[an abstract class] can be extended by only one subclass" false "(Java doesn't support multiple inheritance)" true   Java doesn't support multiple inheritance means a class cannot extend more than one class. But, several subclasses can extend a particular class.
